# Can the nRF24L01+ CE and CSN pins be attached to Arduino pins A0 and A1?

Tags: nrf24l01+

This [documentation](http://playground.arduino.cc/InterfacingWithHardware/Nrf24L01) states that the CE and CSN pins can be specified.  Can I specify A0 and A1 as these pins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The [mirf library](https://github.com/aaronds/arduino-nrf24l01/blob/master/Mirf/Mirf.cpp#L85-86) is using the regular arduino functions `pinMode` and `digitalWrite` to manipulate the pins. So A0 and A1 should work as expected.

Please note that when you use SPI (which the NRF does), you have to use pin 10 (SS) as an OUTPUT (as to not put the AVR into SPI slave mode).

Comment: I'd suggest one would use RF24 (by TMRh20) library so that they are actually using a library that has a active developer who's fixing any library related bugs.